# Analyze some html pages from StackOverflow

Tags: java, eclipse, http, ip, stack-overflow

I need to extract answers from 500 stackoverflow questions at a time, but suddenly I read this error on Eclipse console:

> Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL:
> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=lucene+IndexWriter+registerMerge%28

and if I use browser after that I read this message:

> There are an unusual number of requests coming from this IP address.
>
> To protect our users, we can't process any more requests from this IP address right now.
>
> We'll restore access as quickly as possible, so try again soon.

I do this for a research work. Am I violating some SO rule?

Comment: Have you considered using the API instead of fetching the HTML directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is straightforward: you're screenscraping StackOverflow, and SO doesn't want you doing that.

If you still want to spider the site then just rate-limit your accessing, maybe make one request every 100ms or even 250ms instead of 500 at a time (which is what I assume you're doing).

Comment: OK I do this for a research work and I think that doesn't violate SO rules.